# Sybase - Stored procedure - Store results of a SQL query into an OUTPUT parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqlanywhere

In a stored procedure, I've to build my own SQL request(because tables names and some properties names are known only at execution time(parameters)).

So Basically I've something like this

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH RESULT SET OFF 'My custom query which select one data'
```

Usually, I would use the `INTO` commands, but my parameter is recognized inside the Execute immediate, which seems logic.

(Before you ask: I cannot return this in a result set, the result set is used for another data(and the result of this `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` will determine which query I will run(and must be returned)).

How would you approach this problem? I guess it's the same problem on SQL Server-... but I didn't tested on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a table in compiled Sql and then the dynamic Sql populates it, so that the compiled sql statement after the dynamic part can read the results and update them onto your output params.